# How do I append two newlines if text already exists in file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked around and tried different options for a few hours, but I can't get anything to work properly. I have a code that creates a file and appends the user input in rows as designated by the user.

The problem occurs when a second input (list to str, by the way) is appended into the file. The new input always begins on the same row as the last one ended on.

For example, the output to the file will be:

```
input 1
input 1
input 1input 2
input 2
input 2
```

The issue is that the second input starts on the last line of the first input, I want it to start on a newline.

I tried various things, like having the code look if readline / read () and (1) exists in the file, but I never got it to work.

Currently, the relevant section of my code looks like this:

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Sam's Calendar"))
with open(str(now.year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '-' + str(daterange).zfill(2) + '.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(reminderdescriptionfull))
```

I'd like an answer that's comprehensible to someone who's not very adept at writing code if at all possible.

Comment: You skillfully avoided to state your actual problem

Comment: I stated my actual problem. It's that the second inputs first line gets added to the last line of the first input. The three replies so far seems to have understood.

Comment: Could you clarify one thing here? Are you looking to change the code that's writing to the file? Or, do you want to clean up the file that has already been written to?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait - I wrote out the answer but forgot to send it. I am looking to change the code. Amit Nanaware's answer worked out for me, but feel free to add your own ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Sam's Calendar"))
with open(str(now.year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '-' + str(daterange).zfill(2) + '.txt', 'a+') as file:
        if reminderdescriptionfull:
             file.write("%s\n"%'\n'.join(reminderdescriptionfull))
```

Comment: could you please explain what have you added and what effect it will bring.

Comment: I used `"%s\n"` which adds new line at the end so next time the write will start from the new line not from the last line

Comment: Worked very well for the most part. However, I like to think of the small details, too, and this adds the newline even if the input is empty. Would it be possible to only add the newline if input is not empty?

Comment: Check the updated answer. You can add the if condition to check if input is not empty.

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I was after, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a final newline in your write. Just add an extra statement inside the `with`:

```
file.write('\n')
```

and you should find the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Join interleaves a newline character between the lines in `reminderdescriptionfull`, hence, there is no newline at the end of one input or the beginning of the other. To work around around this problem, all you have to do is add a newline character while writing to the file, i.e.,

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Sam's Calendar"))
with open(str(now.year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '-' + str(daterange).zfill(2) + '.txt', 'a+') as file:
        file.write('{}\n'.format('\n'.join(reminderdescriptionfull)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of checking if a file is empty is using `os.stat.st_size`.

```
import os
os.stat("file").st_size
```

But since you alread have the file opened, you could also just try to read the first character and see if there's anything there:

```
with open("path/to/file", "a+") as file:
    if file.read(1):
        file.write('\n\n')
    # now the rest of your output
```

You mentioned that you've already tried checking `file.read()`, but the above snippet (and the `os` snippet) should get you what you're after.